# Finding functions $g$ such that the Fourier transform of $g(x+c)g(x)$ does not vanish

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose that $f$ is a function of the form
$$
f(x) = g(x+c)g(x),
$$
i.e. $f$ is a product of $g$ with a shifted $g$. If $g$ is a Gaussian, so is $f$ for every $c \in \mathbb R$. In particular, the Fourier transform of $f$ does not vanish.

Does there exist other functions with this property or even a class of functions $g$ such that the Fourier transform of $x \mapsto g(x+c)g(x)$ does not vanish for every $c$?

Comment: Any function $g$ that satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g^2(x) dx \neq \infty$ and $\forall c\; \exists x , g(x+c)g(x) \neq 0$ will work.

Comment: could you provide a proof of this? (don't see immediately why this suffices)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "vanished"?, I believe that because of the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma [[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)] almost every function with finite Lebesgue integral will have a Fourier transform that vanishes at infinity.